# How to write term none in alloy

Tags: alloy

I have write the code like accesses = none. But if I execute metamodel the message appears

```
 Cannot bind field accesses to the empty set or empty relation
```

How to fix my code ?

```
sig months_prior_to_open_day extends BusinessEvent {} { 
    triggers = open_day_planning accesses = none
} 

sig open_day_planning extends BusinessProcess {} { 
    flows_to = none 
    realizes = none 
    uses = none 
    aggregates = none 
    triggers = send_update_to_subject_staff 
    accesses = none 
}
```

Comment: Please provide a short example that can be run in Alloy. This is too little information to answer.

Comment: sig months_prior_to_open_day extends BusinessEvent {}{
    triggers = open_day_planning
    accesses = none}

sig open_day_planning extends BusinessProcess {}{
    flows_to = none
    realizes = none
    uses = none
    aggregates = none
    triggers = send_update_to_subject_staff
    accesses = none
}

Comment: This code does not compile since parts like BusinessEvent are missing. Please make a short example that demonstrates your problem. Also, look at how to format StackOverflow messages. You can edit your original message.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing `no accesses` instead.

Comment: module openday 

sig BusinessEvent {}

sig BusinessProcess{}

sig months_prior_to_open_day extends BusinessEvent 
{
    triggers=open_day_planning
   accesses = none
}

sig open_day_planning extends BusinessProcess {}{
    flows_to=none 
    realizes=none 
    uses=none
    aggregates = none
    triggers = send_update_to_subject_staff
    accesses = none
}